# Crossbrowser background stretching using background-size

Tags: cross-browser, css

I have a background image that is 40px wide and 1200px high which I would like to use as a background image for a site. In most cases users monitors are not large enough to exceed 1200px so I can just use "background-repeat: repeat-x" and the image will span the entire background. For larger monitors though a gap will be visible at the bottom.

To get around this I am trying to use the background-size property. For Firefox this works pretty well, e.g.:

```
background-image: url('gradient.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-size: 40px 100%;
```

But on Webkit-based browsers this does not behave as expected.

Any suggestions?

**--Edit--**

One thing I forgot to mention: when I use a pixel value for the height, background-size works in webkit as well. The problem is, however, I would then need to use JavaScript to set the height initially and each time the browser is resized, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-webkit-background-size: 40px 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks Mohag519. I did try that but unfortunately that still doesn't achieve the right affect. The browsers I'm testing on at the moment are Chrome 11 and Epiphany 2.30.6.

Answer (score 1):

Think the background sizing is still a bit experimental.

I'd reccomend that you either let the background fade (using a gradient) to a solid color that is the same as the background-color. Or make the image vertically seamless, and let it repeat in both directions depending on what works best for the background in question.

You could use the background-size (and proprietary versions) as well, but use the repeat or fade trick as a fallback.

Comment: Hi Stein, Thanks for the suggestion. If I could remember how I designed the gradient in the first place I would certainly redo it so that it fades to a solid color. Unfortunately after a few attempts I couldn't recreate something quite as nice as what I have now. I will still keep a reasonable background-color as a fallback since it isn't *too* obvious, but since the background-size works perfectly on recent versions of Firefox, I am hoping to try and replicate that in other browsers when possible.